# Yielding a thread from another thread (lua)

Tags: lua

I am trying to create a sleep function for Lua, since my Lua-Scripts all run in a different thread/environment I wanted to yield their thread and restart from the main thread when the given amount of time elapsed, the main thread is in Java and the time elapsing is done with a loop.

Now this isn't really hard or something but I am trying to use Lua's own coroutines/threads so I don't have to create my own thread structure but (my Lua knowledge isn't top-notch) I don't know how I can yield a thread from outside of the thread.

Is it possible to yield a thread from the main thread?

**Edit** Nevermind, I just figured it out. I did a getfenv and used the coroutine.yield of the script it's own environment.

Comment: If you found the answer, perhaps you can answer your own question, helping users who will come up with the same question in the future.

Comment: I explained what I did in the edit.

Comment: It's better to really answer it (doesn't even matter if you just copy paste). Otherwise your question stays unanswered. See also [here](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/07/its-ok-to-ask-and-answer-your-own-questions/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I used the script it's coroutine.yield function. Pretty easy looking back at it